# Insert html code in between a Laravel PHP bracket

Tags: php, html, laravel, string

How can I insert html code or line break in between a string inside the Laravel PHP bracket?

```
`{{ __('this word on top' . <br/> . 'this word will be below') }}`
```

Something like this

I tried putting the html code but it doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Are you sure this problem is related to HTML after all?

Comment: Why do you want to add markup to your translation strings after all?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Because we want to translate the whole string but want to add break line specifically in a certain part.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```
{!! __('this word on top <br/> this word will be below') !!}.
```

Be very careful when echoing content that is supplied by users of your application. You should typically use the escaped, double curly brace syntax to prevent XSS attacks when displaying user supplied data.
For more information refer the laravel official docs https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade